# Java Overriding issue

Tags: java

I have class Shape that is inherited by class Rectangle as below:

```
//Class Shape
public class Shape {
    public double area(){
        return 0.0;
    }
}

//Class  Rectangle 
public class Rectangle extends Shape{

    private int width;
    private int height;
    public Rectangle(int width,int height){
        this.width=width;
        this.height=height;
    }

    public void helloRectange(){
        System.out.println("Hello Rectangle");
    }


    public double area(){
        return this.height*this.width;
    }

}

//And Test Class


public class TestShape {

    public static void main(String []arge){

        Shape shape2=new Rectangle(10,20);

        shape2.helloRectange();


        System.out.println("Rectange is"+shape2.area());
    }

}
```

I am unable to call `shape2.helloRectange();` method using `shape2` object? Can somebody explain in detail.

The error is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: The method `helloRectange()` is undefined for the type Shape at com.test.overriding.concept.TestShape.main(TestShape.java:9)

Comment: Note that it is good practice to annotate method overrides with `@Override`. This will tell you immediately if you have a method that's legal but doesn't match the one you were trying to override.

Answer (score 4):

Because `Shape` class doesn't have the method `helloRectange` , change:

`Shape shape2=new Rectangle(10,20);`

to:

`Rectangle shape2=new Rectangle(10,20);`

or cast the object like:

`((Rectangle)shape2).helloRectange();`

Answer (score 2):

For proper Polymorphism, you should declare Shape abstract and add a hello method to it.

Then, in Rectangle, create a hello method with the same arguments.

It'd look something like this:

```
//Class Shape
public abstract class Shape {
    public abstract void hello();
    public double area(){
        return 0.0;
    }
}

//Class  Rectangle 
public class Rectangle extends Shape{

    private int width;
    private int height;
    public Rectangle(int width,int height){
        this.width=width;
        this.height=height;
    }

    @Override
    public void hello(){
        System.out.println("Hello Rectangle");
    }


    public double area(){
        return this.height*this.width;
    }

}
```

Then this would work

```
//And Test Class


public class TestShape {

    public static void main(String []arge){

        Shape shape2=new Rectangle(10,20);

        shape2.hello();


        System.out.println("Rectange is"+shape2.area());
    }

}
```

Do note that all methods in Java are [virtual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function).  This isn't true of all languages and in things like C# you might have to specify the virtual keyword (`abstract` may automatically imply `virtual`, though)

Comment: Maybe he doesn't want all the shape objects to have a hello method.

Comment: @PacoAbato Then he shouldn't try to call that method on a Shape :P.

Comment: @Powerlord That issue is what other answers try to solve. Who knows what's in the OP's mind :D Hopefully he'll tell us.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is a `Shape` object, and shape does not have the `helloRectange` function. Try making it a Rectangle:

```
Rectangle shape2 = new Rectangle(10,20);
shape2.helloRectange();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Shape shape2=new Rectangle(10,20);
```

That line alone means that execute the implementations of Rectangle class of Shape class methods. Since Shape doesn't have a method helloRectangle, you cannot access it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that because you used polymorphic assignment and static type of your objects is `Shape`. Even though the dynamic type is `Rectangle` and the object has the method on itself you cannot call it without a cast:

```
((Rectangle)shape2).helloRectangle();
```

That happens because the compiler doesn't know the dynamic type of the object and hence is not aware that the method exists there.

Read more about static/dynamic polymorphism:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/neutral-137988.html

http://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/runtime-compile-time-polymorphism/

Comment: Thank you... So we can assume that compiler is not smart enough to understand the derived class have other methods too.. Could you provide me some reference related to this logic.

Comment: Besides it's not compiler's fault, you basically tell it: "This is a Shape" in you assignment so it has no way to know that in fact it's subclass of Shape. It will know during the runtime though